# PL/SQL: Declare variable and select table where condition depends on the variable

Tags: variables, plsql, conditional-statements, plsqldeveloper, declare

What is the simplest way, I can create an PL/SQL-query that

1. Declares some variables, e.g. a `date='30Sep2022'` and an `id=2000`
2. Select data from a table where it conditions on `col_date = date and col_id = id`

Answer (score 2):

You specifically asked for PL/SQL, which is Oracle's procedural extension to SQL. In it, you can't just "`SELECT`"; it has to be "`SELECT INTO`" *something* (variable, collection, ref cursor, whatever).

You didn't explain what you mean by the "simplest" way; one of them is to create a function that returns ref cursor, while "variables" are passed as its parameters:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test (par_datum IN DATE, par_id IN NUMBER)
  2     RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  3  IS
  4     rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  5  BEGIN
  6     OPEN rc FOR SELECT *
  7                   FROM test
  8                  WHERE     datum = par_datum
  9                        AND id = par_id;
 10
 11     RETURN rc;
 12  END f_test;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT f_test (DATE '2023-03-13', 10) result FROM DUAL;

RESULT
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO         ID ENAME      JOB       DATUM
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- --------
      7782         10 CLARK      MANAGER   13.03.23
      7839         10 KING       PRESIDENT 13.03.23


SQL>
```

---

Another option is to use variables in tool that supports them; for example, SQL*Plus. Its *drawback* is that you can't declare variables whose datatype is `DATE`, so you rely on implicit datatype conversion or have to use function which deals with it.

```
SQL> var par_id number
SQL> var par_datum varchar2(10)
SQL>
SQL> exec :par_id := 20

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec :par_datum := '13.03.2023'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test
  2  where id = :par_id
  3    and datum = to_date(:par_datum, 'dd.mm.yyyy');

     EMPNO         ID ENAME      JOB       DATUM
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- --------
      7369         20 SMITH      CLERK     13.03.23
      7788         20 SCOTT      ANALYST   13.03.23
      7902         20 FORD       ANALYST   13.03.23

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is very different from what I expected. I am used to work in Microsoft SQL where you can "just select" using a query. There is it also very easy to create variables which would be used in the query - by using declare and the "add"-symbole (`@`). 

In my new job, we are using Oracle SQL (namely PL/SQL through PL/SQL developer). To me it seems like, I can still "just select" using a query like `select * from table_name`.

Much of the stuff you mention like function, cursors, etc. is new to me. Do you have a link to the official/good documentation?

Comment: This is official Oracle 10g (yes, I know - it is old, desupported): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/index.htm but it is nicely divided into several sections. Have a look at "Most popular" and read Concepts (to get familiar with Oracle). As you're developer, go to SQL Reference, then PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference and - finally - Application Developer's Guide - Fundamentals. These should get you started with Oracle. All documentation is available on https://docs.oracle.com/en/ so - pick version you're using and check the same books I already suggested.

Comment: @Landscape PL/SQL is a programming language provided as part of the Oracle toolset, not a query language or even really a scripting language. SQL is a query language. Oracle SQL isn't called 'PL/SQL', if that's what you mean by *we are using Oracle SQL (namely PL/SQL through PL/SQL developer).*